# Dynamically add Id or name to option

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a select combo box. And now I am dynamically adding some options to it. I can add a value und a text. But I also want to add an Id or name to it. I already tried .prop('name',someName) or .attr('name',someName), but somehow this is not working.

```
$("[id='"+  p.name + "']").append($('<option</option>').val(p1.id).text(p1.name));
```

Comment: Hi @blurry333, are you clicking on button?

Comment: Firstly `$("[id='"+  p.name + "']")` needs to be changed to `$('#' + p.name)`. Secondly, for what reason do you feel the need to put `id` on an `option` element? They shouldn't be needed. Also `name` isn't a valid attribute for an `option`, so you shouldn't do that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$` as `jQuery( html, attributes )`:

```
$('<option>', {'id':'yourid', 'value':'yourvalue', text: 'yourtext'});
```

look https://jsbin.com/naqoyihimo/edit?html,output

Comment: I tried this, but in my case it was not working                                                                                                $("[id='"+  p.name + "']").append($('<option>', {name:'yourid', value:'yourvalue', text: 'yourtext'}));

Comment: @blurry333 it does, problem must me somewhere else (I've added working example to my answer)

Comment: thanks a lot. It is really weird why in my case it does not work. Maybe because I use a multiselect combo box. But I have to check further. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to use id for an option, but you can try this way

```
$('"#"'+p.name+'').append($('<option value='+p1.id+' id="someid" name="somename">'+p1.name+'</option>'));
```